# SwiftUI - Update password on Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to be able to update at my password on Firebase , but it's not working yet. Hope you can help me to solve this problem

Form

```
struct ChangePassword: View {
    @State var oldPassword: String = ""
    @State var newPassword: String = ""
    @State var confirmPassword : String = ""
    @ObservedObject var loginViewModel = LoginViewModel()
    var body: some View {
       ZStack {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Old Pw")
                    .poppinsRegularFont(size: 17)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1))).opacity(1)
                SecureField("", text: $oldPassword)
                    .padding()
                    .font(Font.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .serif))
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 80,height: 48)
                    .background(
                        Color.black.opacity(0.1)
                    )
            }
            .padding(.bottom,20)
            HStack {
                Text("New Pw")
                    .poppinsRegularFont(size: 17)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1))).opacity(1)
                SecureField("", text: $newPassword)
                    .padding()
                    .font(Font.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .serif))
                    .background(
                        Color.black.opacity(0.1)
                    )
            }
            .padding(.bottom,20)
            HStack {
                Text("Confirm Pw")
                    .poppinsRegularFont(size: 17)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1))).opacity(1)
                SecureField("", text: $confirmPassword)
                    .padding()
                    .font(Font.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .serif))
                    .background(
                        Color.black.opacity(0.1)
                    )
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                loginViewModel.updatePassword(password: confirmPassword)
            }) {
                Text("Save")
            }
        }
       }
    }
}
```

func UpdatePassword

```
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
 let userPassword = Auth.auth().currentUser
    var credential: AuthCredential?
    
    func updatePassword(password: String) {
        if let credential = credential {
            userPassword?.reauthenticate(with: credential ) { error,_  in
                if error != nil {
                // An error happened.
              } else {
                Auth.auth().currentUser?.updatePassword(to: password) { (error) in
                  // ...
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to be able to update at my password on Firebase , but it's not working yet. Hope you can help me to solve this problem...................................

Comment: Where does a guy named 'credential' come from?

Comment: Where does a guy named 'password' in your Auth.auth().currentUser?.updatePassword(to: password) method come from?

Comment: it's because I read the documentation myself. If something is incorrect, please help me correct it

Comment: @ElTomato i watch it on : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#swift

Comment: As far as I see it you never pass a `credential` to your LoginViewModel. What exactly is the problem? Have you debugged this already?

Comment: I am with the above comments. The `credential` property is never set in your loginViewModel here `@ObservedObject var loginViewModel = LoginViewModel()`. All you do is call the updatePassword function on it but with no credentials, this line `if let credential = credential` will silently fail. It's a good idea to perform debugging before posting as if you would have stepped through the code, that would have been noticed. Also, adding and else statement to that `if` statement `} else { print("credential was nil!") }` would have been very revealing.

Answer (score 1):

```
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

    let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: user!.email!, password: currentPassword)

    user?.reauthenticate(with: credential, completion: { (authResult, error) in
       if let error = error {
          // Handle re-authentication error
          return
       }
       user?.updatePassword(to: newPassword, completion: { (error) in
          if let error = error {
             // Handle password update error
             return
          }
          // Password update successful
       })
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to reauthenticate user , please write below code

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.updatePassword(to: newPasswordTF.text!) { (error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                
            }
            // Password change sucussfully
            

          // ...
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it's a bit inaccurate. From the Firebase documentation [Re-authenticate a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user) which states *Some security-sensitive actions such as deleting an account, setting a primary email address, and **changing a password** require that the user has recently signed in* and in those cases the **user must be re-authenticated** to perform the action. The answer is fine in the cases where the user recently authenticated though. But better to be safe than sorry and end up with a crash.